# What are the pros/cons of using a copula model to price CMS spread options, in particular ones with short expiries?

Tags: copula, spread-options

The expiry of the option may not be relevant to the question, but I would be curious to know if a copula model would provide an accurate price for sub 6 month expiry options.

Comment: Everything is a copula, any relationship implies one. The problem with "copula models" is that standard [parametric copula families](http://stanfordphd.com/Copula.html) are adopted, typically, and those are rigid in the tails. They do not capture all the asymmetries and such.

Answer (score 0):

A copula model for CMS spread options takes as inputs the basis point volatility of each rate and a correlation coefficient.  Typically these are used to calibrate the ATM option, and then a skew is applied for OTM options.

As to whether this is ‘accurate’, what does this mean ?  In my experience, this procedure approximates reasonably closely the market price of ATM options, assuming the 2 vols are the implied vols of the appropriate swaptions and the correlation input is the recent realized correlation between the 2 rates.  However for OTM options typically the procedure underestimates the market price because there is usually a significant skew.

Hence the copula model can be said to be a reasonable pricing methodology, appropriately calibrated, but the fact it doesn’t capture skew means that it is not a very sophisticated approach.

Comment: I agree that a basic copula, such as the gaussian copula, may not capture the asymmetries of the skew very well. Would it be naive to say that copula methods are therefore not very common methods for pricing CMS spreads in markets today? Or perhaps there are more sophisticated copula methods in use?